# Can't access RabbitMQ Management Plugin on CentOS 7

Tags: rabbitmq, centos7

I installed RabbitMQ with the installation tutorial on RabbitMQ website.
I launched rabbitmq-server, enabled management plugin and opened port in CSF but I still can't access the Web Management UI. 
When I try *http://IPadress:15672*, *http://servername:15672* or *http://domain:15672*, I get Unavailable Website, failed to load resource.

I'm using a CentOS 7 server in production.
On my Windows local machine, I installed RabbitMQ and I'm able to access Web management UI.

**RabbitMQ status :**

```
[{pid,24260},
 {running_applications,
 [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.6"},
  {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.6"},
  {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3"},
  {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.13.1"},
  {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.6.6"},
  {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.6"},
  {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.14"},
  {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","5.3.3"},
  {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","0.21"},
  {crypto,"CRYPTO version 2","3.2"},
  {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.6"},
  {rabbit_common,[],"3.6.6"},
  {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.9.8"},
  {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.11"},
  {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","4.9.4"},
  {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.6"},
  {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","1.6.13"},
  {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 2.0.4","2.0.4"},
  {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.2.1"},
  {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.4"},
  {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.4"},
  {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.4"}]},
  {os,{unix,linux}},
  {erlang_version,
 "Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
 [{total,55228096},
  {connection_readers,0},
  {connection_writers,0},
  {connection_channels,0},
  {connection_other,2800},
  {queue_procs,2800},
  {queue_slave_procs,0},
  {plugins,891672},
  {other_proc,18595920},
  {mnesia,68264},
  {mgmt_db,758120},
  {msg_index,51952},
  {other_ets,1446776},
  {binary,29688},
  {code,27081119},
  {atom,992409},
  {other_system,5306576}]},
  {alarms,[]},
  {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
  {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
  {vm_memory_limit,4972414566},
  {disk_free_limit,50000000},
  {disk_free,140686581760},
  {file_descriptors,
 [{total_limit,924},{total_used,2},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,0}]},
  {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,233}]},
  {run_queue,0},
  {uptime,598},
  {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

**Opened ports :**

```
20,21,25,26,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,1883,2077,2078,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,2096,2908,4369,5671,5672,8883,15672,25672,30000:50000, 61613,61614
```

Comment: Try to do `curl -X GET -u guest:guest http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F` on the server and see the result. 
If it works try to use `telnet yourserver 15672` (from another machine) to check the port

Comment: With first command, I get `[]`.
I tried telnet but it says `unable to open a connection to host on port 15672 : Connection failed`

Comment: So it is a firewall problem, try to disable it. Maybe it is not configured in the right way

Comment: Even when I disable the firewall, I have the same error message...

Comment: According to the status, `rabbitq_management` didn't open its TCP port: `{listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},`. Could you please provide RabbitMQ logs?